# XOR sum of everysingle char in string

Tags: c, xor

I've got string out of Receive[300] that starts with delim1 - & and ends with delim2 - *. Now i need to XOR all of the chars inbetween. I think that i need to convert everysingle char into bin and then sum them up. I've been looking for a fuction in "string.h"but there is nothing in there. How should i  solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Which language? Do you know what XOR is?

Comment: I'm programming in C. XOR is Exclusive OR. I need to check if the XOR of chars inbeetween & and * equals 2 bytes after*.
$GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30

Comment: Quote: "I think that i need to convert everysingle char into bin ..." No, you don't. It's already binary inside the machine so just go on with the xor.

Comment: The `char`s *are* in binary. Just XOR them, which is a bitwise operation on an integer, and `char` is an integer type.

Comment: @WeatherVane This might help:

char *ptr = strtok(Received,delim1);

 char *star = strtok(ptr,delim2);

 sum ^= *star;

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. See [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for code formatting help.

Comment: This might sounds stupid but i'm ashamed of it! It's really bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop.

```
char *ptr = strtok(Received, delim1);
char *star = strtok(ptr, delim2);
char result = ptr[0]; // Start with the first character in the token
if (ptr[0]) { // don't loop if the string is empty
    for (char *p = ptr+1; *p; p++) { // Loop over the remaining characters
        result ^= *p; // XOR them into the result
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/WaUhK5)

Comment: but how to determine when does the last char of the token appear? ( * ) 

in this code it starts with & and stop when another & appears - To count mnea checksum i need to countr between & and *. Or am i wrong?

Comment: `strtok()` replaces the delimiter with a null byte. So the `*` becomes the end of the token that begins with `&`. The `*p` test in my loop checks for that.

Comment: something is wrong, or at least i do not understand. After declaring char *ptr = strtok(Received,delim1); we want to go through everysingle char that is remaining before " * " appears. However STM STUDIO - doesn't show any changes.

Comment: Did you also declare `char *star = strtok(ptr, delim2);` first? You need that to replace the `*` with a null byte.

Comment: Yes i did, whenever interrput happens (data arrives) - i receive data from GPS -> declare char *ptr and char *star and run this loop. i understand the idea of this loop however the sum (result in your code) stays the same.

Comment: I've added a demo, I get different sums for different inputs.

Comment: im reading it atm. The problem is that "Received" is an array of data (char[284]) that GPS is sending every single second.  Inside of the 284 arrays there are strings that starts with & and end with * - i want to seperate them and count the checksum nmea. i need to pass the data and xor it (i think within interruption)

Comment: If there can be multiple `&...*` strings in the data, you just need to use a loop that runs until `strtok()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: does "p" mean one element out of 284 char array "Received"?

Comment: https://ideone.com/vrJDIg  the returned sum should equals to the XOR of taken string

Comment: Yeah, I realized that I'm using `strtok()` wrong. It probably should just use `strchr()` instead.

Comment: using `strchr()` won't provide the end of the string - at least that what i think

Comment: im trying to understand the changes in DEMO provided by you  - it works as console app. Im using stm32 - trying to convert data provided by GPS module Neo 7. It transmit data to UART's Rx all the time - i need to split that. When interrupts occur - i need to use your function with gps's data